# Set difference in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a table temp(a int) that stores (1),(2) and (3). I've another table temp2(a int) that stores only (1). I want the values that are in only temp. My try:-

```
  SELECT a FROM temp WHERE a NOT IN temp2;
```

I get an error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "temp2"  LINE 1: SELECT a FROM temp WHERE a NOT IN temp2;".

Why is that so? And what's the correct way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: What about duplicates? If there are two 4 in temp, but only one 4 in temp2, what's the expected result?

Answer (score 19):

Another option is to use `EXCEPT`

```
select a 
from temp
except
select a
from temp2;
```

Answer (score 4):

You already have good answers, i just wanted to add one.
You could also go with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT temp.a
FROM temp 
LEFT JOIN temp2 
ON temp.a = temp2.a
WHERE temp2.a IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

use not in like below

```
SELECT a FROM temp WHERE a NOT IN ( select a from temp2 where a is not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM temp t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp2 t2 WHERE t2.a = t.a);
```